# Is it still possible to use pipenv with Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, pipenv

I have Python2.7 & Python3.8 installed on my computer with pipenv. I managed to create a 2.7 project by running the following command:

```
pipenv --two install
pipenv shell
> python --version
> > Python 2.7.15
```

But when I tried to install a new dependancy using pipenv I got an TLS error due to SNIMissingWarning:

```
pip install pylint
...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting astroid==1.6.6 (from -r C:\\Users\\aymeric\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pipenv-pktqf1dv-requirements\\pipenv-66rq3_4k-requirement.txt (line 1))', "  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/astroid/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/astroid/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping"]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ["DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. 
Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. 
More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support",  'c:\\users\\aymeric\\.virtualenvs\\firmware-pjqfwcnq\\lib\\site-packages\\ pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\util\\ssl_.py:365: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. 
This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. 
You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this.
For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings', '  SNIMissingWarning', 'c:\\users\\aymeric\\.virtualenvs\\firmware-pjqfwcnq\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\util\\ssl_.py:149: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail.
```

Which is odd because SNIMissingWarning should have been patch in 2.7.9 as explained in [this link](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings)

If remote repositories are now unreachable from 2.7 virtualenv how can you do?
Kinds regards

Comment: The problem is `SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version')`, which means pip tried to connect to PyPI using an incompatible TLS version.

Comment: Thanks, but for me the underlying error is : `SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. 
This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. `